# How implement a "next" button in a fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android, i just created a Tabbed Activity from the gallery of android studio.

Now I want create a button that let me switch from the page 1 to page 2 of the fragment, how can i do that?

Couldn't find any example that use the "Tabbed Activity" of android studio.

**EDIT** after the answer of Neelay Srivastava:

Here is my code now:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        bn1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b_next1);
        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1) {

            bn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View V)
                {
                    Fragment someFragment = new Replacement();  <--- ERROR HERE
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frag5 , someFragment ); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            });
        }
```

I did it but i got:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Replacement'

Comment: Start by adding a button to your XML layout and a `OnClickListener` to perform an action when the user clicks the button.

Comment: mostly in tabbed we use view pager to swipe and change the fragment

Comment: yea but how can i change the fragment without the swipe but with a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go to one fragment to another fragment by a button you have to set some thing like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_album, container, false);

Button button =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment someFragment = new Replacement();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.replace_frag, someFragment ); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
return view;
```

}

here `replacefrag` is the id of the layout you want to replace so you have to set the id of the layout

Comment: I tried but got 1 error, question updated with more details

Comment: bro thats the name of the fragment you want to replace